# SCVMM 2008 R2 Powershell Commands

Tags: hyper-v, powershell, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, scvmm

I am running SCVMM 2008 R2 with 3 hosts.  Right now I am patching the hosts, so I am running the command

```
disable-vmhost hostA -MoveWithinCluster
```

Is there a command that I can run or switch I can enable to direct where the machines on hostA get migrated to?  What happened last time I ran it was all the machines migrated to a host that was already hosting numerous VMs and there was another host that was completely empty.

Answer (score 2):

That option doesn't exist in that specific commandlet.

However you can achieve the result you want by getting all the hosts on the node with the `get-vm` command and then piping them to the `move-vm` to a host you specify. After that you can run `disable-vmhost` to prevent machines from moving back there during maintenance.

Example:

```
Get-VM|?{$_.VMHost -eq 'hostA'}|Move-VM -VMHost 'HostB'
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will give that a try.  I believe though I would have a similar problem since it would move all the moves to HostB.  I have seen a script that evaluates the Host Rating and moves all the VMs to the highest rated host.  I appreciate your answer